# Challenge to change source date formats to desired date formats

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl

Someone, please assist me in solving this challenge:

I am using Zappsys Json Source on my dataflow and trying to transfer date to the OLEDB destination.

Googlespreadsheet Source: `ActualClosingDate` : `7/29/16` as `m/dd/yy` format

I want to convert it to OLEDB destination as

`2016-07-29 15:00:00:000`  format using derived column expression.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues have you had? What data type is the target column?

Answer (score 0):

Take a drived column component and convert the date as expected like following example:

```
(DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART("yyyy",GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0" + "-" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("mm",GETDATE()),2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("dd",GETDATE()),2) + "-" + "  " + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("hour", GETDATE()) + ":" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("minute", GETDATE())+ ":" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("second", GETDATE()) + ":" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("millisecond", GETDATE())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To convert this value to a DateTime value, you can simply use a cast operator in a derived column as follows:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)[ActualClosingDate]
```

If you are looking to store this column as a string with a specific format (since DateTime columns have no format) just reconvert it to a string, and it will automatically ISO formatted:

```
(DT_WSTR,50)(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)[ActualClosingDate]
```